What does Visual Studio Code actually run when pressing F5 (debug)?
I'm developing an Azure Function App using Visual Studio Code:
I've generated settings and tasks using the Azure Functions: Initialize Project for Use with VS Code... command.
Several guides instruct me to start the function app by pressing F5 (debug). In this case, what is actually being run? Does Visual Studio Code execute one of the generated tasks (see below)?
Note: When starting the function app by pressing F5 (debug), the Swagger UI endpoints are shown, but not if run I the host start task directly (why?)
tasks.json:
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "clean (functions)",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "args": [
                "clean",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "type": "process",
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/AssetGovernance"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "build (functions)",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "type": "process",
            "dependsOn": "clean (functions)",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/AssetGovernance"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "clean release (functions)",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "args": [
                "clean",
                "--configuration",
                "Release",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "type": "process",
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/AssetGovernance"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "publish (functions)",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "args": [
                "publish",
                "--configuration",
                "Release",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "type": "process",
            "dependsOn": "clean release (functions)",
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/AssetGovernance"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "func",
            "dependsOn": "build (functions)",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/AssetGovernance/bin/Debug/net8.0"
            },
            "command": "host start",
            "isBackground": true,
            "problemMatcher": "$func-dotnet-watch"
        }
    ]
}


Are you getting any error?

Is your issue resolved? @Shuzheng

F5 should utilize launch.json from your .vscode - folder so I assume that you are not utilizing the correct task. launch.json is usually generated automatically by vscode when you start to debug first time.
See more details from here
